# Adding functionality to my search and select filter outside ng-app - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The directive inside my controller is simply list items with data from my api call. HTML for that:

```
<div ng-app="WWnetworkEvents"> 
<ul ng-controller ="networkEventsCtrl">
    <networkevent-directive></networkevent-directive>
</ul>
```

This is my directive html:

```
<li ng-repeat="event in events | filter:queryevents | orderBy:orderProp" > 
<h2>{{event.title}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Posted on:{{event.date | myDateFormat }}</li>
        <li>Tickets available:{{event.tickets}}</li>
        <li>Details:{{event.body}}</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Outside of my WWnetworkEvents module, i have the following search and filter options, but I don't know how would I bind them, if they are outside of my ng-app:

```
<h2>Search Events</h2>
<input type="search" ng-model="queryevents">
<h2>Filter Events</h2>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="title">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="-date" >Newest</option>
    <option value="date" >Oldest</option>
    <option value="-tickets">Tickets Left</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ng-modules. You can install it with bower by running:

```
bower install ng-module
```

More info here: https://github.com/luisperezphd/ngModule

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two ways to handle your situation.

1. Use `ng-repeat` outside directive.
   This might require some work getting everything to work again.
2. Use `$broadcast' or`$emit' to make your directive aware of the changes on the `ng-model="queryevents"` and `ng-model="orderProp"`. Once your directive is aware of the changes then you can use `$filter` in your controller to filter the required data.